# Finding relationship count as per latitude and longitude in Laravel App

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build an application on Laravel. I've a model `Project` which has `id`, `name`, `state_id`, `city_id` , `latitude`, `longitude`, `status`, and `timestamps`

I tried adding a nearby feature which finds the project as per the latitude and longitude constrains. My query is:

```
$projects = Project::where('projects.status', 'saved')
    ->selectRaw("*,
     ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
       cos( radians( latitude ) )
       * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?)
       ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
       sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
     ) AS distance", [request('latitude'), request('longitude'), request('latitude')])->having("distance", "<", request('range')
    ->with('state', 'city')
    ->orderBy('projects.updated_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(50)
```

This works as desired, Now I need to find out count of projects associated with states/city as per the above query, I tried:

```
$states = State::withCount(['projects' => function ($q){
    $q->selectRaw("*,
         ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
           cos( radians( latitude ) )
           * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?)
           ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
           sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
         ) AS distance", [request('latitude'), request('longitude'), request('latitude')])->having("distance", "<", request('range')
    }])
    ->orderBy('states.name', 'desc')->paginate();
```

I'm getting an error with MySQL

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause' (SQL: select `states`.*, (select count(*) from `projects` where `states`.`id` = `projects`.`state_id`.....

What is the better way to implement this?

Comment: I would have thought that any way that works is 'better'. If it was me, I'd start with the sql.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely to be Eloquent prefixing the database and table names to `distance` in the `having()` call.

As `distance` was an alias created in `selectRaw`, you will need to use `havingRaw()`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#havingraw-orhavingraw

`->havingRaw('distance < ?', request('range'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
$lat = $request->latitude ?? '';
$lng = $request->longitude ?? '';
$distance = $request->range ?? '';
$states = State::query();
$states = $states::withCount(['projects' => function ($q) use ($lat,$lng,$distance){
    $haversineSQL = "( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('{$lat}') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('{$lng}') ) + sin( radians('{$lat}') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )";
    $states = $states->whereRaw($haversineSQL . '< ?', $distance);
}])->orderBy('name', 'desc')->paginate(2);
```

**OR**

```
$states = State::withCount(['projects' => function ($query) use ($lat,$lng,$distance){
        $query->select(\DB::raw('*,( COALESCE( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) ) AS distance'))->having('distance', '<', $distance );
    }])->orderBy('name', 'desc')->paginate(2);
```